# Append Key/Value pair to L.Control.layer in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, controls, layer

Here is a simplified example of my "issue."

I have a list of key/value pairs like this:

```
var baseMaps = {"thing1": thing1,
                 "thing2": thing2};

var overlayMaps = {"OverLay1": link to overlay2
                    "Overlay2": link to overlay2};
```

etc...........

I can uses this code to add on to my object list:

```
overlayMaps["New Item"] = link to new item;
```

I verify on the console that it's added to the overlayMaps list.

Issue:  It does not show up in the box on the side of the map like all the other ones. They are in a box with little check marks by them to turn them on and off. Am I missing some code to do this? It seems like I need a way to refresh the layer group list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code is as per the example in [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html).

```
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

The problem is you've lost reference to the control instance because didn't assign it to anything. Since the addTo method is chainable it will give you the control.

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Now you can access it in your code and run its methods like layerControl.[addBaseLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#control-layers-addbaselayer)